# How do you avoid scanning the whole BigQuery table when querying a table created by Datastream?

Tags: google-datastream

Have just created a stream from PostreSQL to BigQuery using Datastream and was pretty pleased with the results. For each table I altered the DDL after initial streaming to add daily partitions on our created_at fields assuming everything would work as it has done on our previous version of this dataset. However, the partitions are not referenced or honored when querying the data so am left with inefficient and expensive queries scanning and billing the whole table each time.

Quick example with one of our tables for the same simple query:

```
-- Original table NOT using Datastream, let's call the dataset "original"
SELECT max(created_at), count(1) FROM original.orders WHERE date(created_at) = '2023-05-01';

-- Query processes 1.62MB


-- New table using Datastream, let's call the dataset "datastream"
SELECT max(created_at), count(1) FROM datastream.orders WHERE date(created_at) = '2023-05-01';

-- Query processes 3.18GB
```

When looking into the execution details there is perhaps some insight into what is happening. The query on the datastream version of the table actually references two separate tables and then combines them. The tables have prefixes on them (1) `datastream.DELTA_CDC_TABLE_orders` and (2) `datastream.CDC_TABLE_orders`
It makes sense that the DELTA table might not be partitioned yet and hence have to scan everything not yet added to the main table, but don't understand why the `CDC_TABLE_orders` can't utilize partitions.

Anyone have ideas how to write the query so that it has to use the partitions and not scan the full table? Couldn't find anything in the documentation around this

Have tried looking into querying for a table suffix, changing the format of the partition ('YYYYMMDD', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'), searching for the CDC_TABLE_ version of the table

Comment: what column(s) did you add for the daily partitions?  you just need to reference them in the WHERE clause to take advantage rather than applying a function on created_at which will have to scan all the rows

Comment: The partition is on the created_at field and this is being applied in the WHERE clause of the queries already. The date function around created_at doesn't have any impact on partitioning, it should still prune the table

Comment: I'm no expert but my hunch is the date function around created_at is what is causing the engine to ignore partitions.  You're not comparing any value to the partition column, but to a function return value, so it has to call the function on every row and then apply the filter

Comment: try something like `where created_at >= '2023-05-01' and created_at < '2023-05-02'` where you directly compare the partition column in the filter

Comment: or change your partition to a column that contains only the truncated date part and compare directly to that

Comment: Partitions work fine with date functions applied, the partition is actually on date(created_at). This seems to be an issue specific to Datastream and the prefixed tables it queries against

Comment: Max_staleness table option seems to be the solution here

Answer (score 0):

I saw your comment about max_staleness and I`m not sure how that helps, but maybe you can try periodically moving data to another partitioned table. This issue seems to be related to the streaming buffer that Datastream keeps and where it keeps it although it should work on a ordinary table with streaming inserts.

Comment: As you are not providing a concrete answer and rather suggesting something, this should not be an answer and rather a comment. Once you earn enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you'll be able to [comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)